# Module `expo` does not exist in the Haste module map

Tags: node.js, github, npm-install, expo, tunneling

I am trying to create a react-native bundle and getting the following error:

```
Unable to resolve module `expo` from `C:\Users\<User>\Projects\myProject\src\HomeScreen\HomeScreen.js`: Module `expo` does not exist in the Haste module map

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm star
t -- --reset-cache`.  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native
-packager-*`.
```

Any clue how do I install the expo module. Tried doing `npm --proxy=http_proxy_server:proxy_port install --save expo` but it fails with following error:

```
npm ERR! fetch failed https://github.com/expo/react-native-maps/archive/0.20.1-e
xp.0.tar.gz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: tunneling socket could
not be established, statusCode=400
npm ERR! fetch failed https://github.com/expo/node-websql/archive/18.0.0.tar.gz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: tunneling socket could
not be established, statusCode=400
npm ERR! fetch failed https://github.com/expo/react-native-maps/archive/0.20.1-e
xp.0.tar.gz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: tunneling socket could
not be established, statusCode=400
npm ERR! fetch failed https://github.com/expo/node-websql/archive/18.0.0.tar.gz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: tunneling socket could
not be established, statusCode=400
npm ERR! fetch failed https://github.com/expo/react-native-maps/archive/0.20.1-e
xp.0.tar.gz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://github.com/expo/node-websql/archive/18.0.0.tar.gz
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "expo"
npm ERR! node v7.9.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above problem was due to proxy limiting access to github.com. I connected to a non-proxy network and cleared my proxy settings from `.npmrc` and also used the following instructions on terminal:

```
npm config delete proxy -g
npm config delete http-proxy -g
npm config delete https-proxy -g
git config --global --unset core.gitproxy
```

After above changes to my machine, I ran the following command and it worked!

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```